# set text for cells in uitable different

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a table with a few rows, and the place holder text for all is the same.  How can I programmatically change the placeholder text of only the first one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run an if statement to check the index of the cell. 0 is the first index, so you would need to check to see if the row is 0.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil) {
           cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
       }
       if (indexPath.row == 0) 
           cell.textLabel.text = @"First Cell";
       else
           cell.textLabel.text = @"Not First Cell";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your cell AFTER the cell was created/reused, try the `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method of your uitableview object! See the [following](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Apple doc for a detailed elaboration on this method. 
Note:

> Return Value
>
> An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not
>   visible or indexPath is out of range.